# Programmatically add default data to custom module - Odoo v9 community

Tags: python, odoo, qweb

I have a custom module, which inherits `fleet.vehicle.log.services` model

This is a custom module.

What I'm trying to do, is to add default data to just two fields of it, let me explain myself.

The model has these mandatory fields:

```
vehicle_id
cost_id
cost_type
```

And I've inherited/added these ones:

```
x_location_src_id
x_location_dest_id
```

These are `stock` locations, what I want is to add default stock locations to this model, but just the locations, not the mandatory fields.

So far, I've tried like this, in my `data/location_data.xml` file:

```
<record id="location_default" model="fleet.vehicle.log.services">
    <field name="vehicle_id">1</field>
    <field name="cost_id">2</field>
    <field name="cost_type">fuel</field>
    <field name="x_location_src_id">ReparacionUnidades</field>
    <field name="x_location_dest_id">ReparacionUnidades</field>
</record>
```

But it doesn't work for me, because, as I've said, I don't need the first three fields, just the last two ones.

So, as this is the only way to add default data by QWeb/XMl, I think there is a way to overcome this, by some `attributes` or maybe programmatically with python.

Do You have a clue on how to do it in some other way?

As I said, I want to bypass the fact that I have to add these other fields, because it makes no sense to me.

Any ideas?

Maybe some logic or attributes into `stock.locations` and not directly into this `fleet.vehicle.log.services` model?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Do you ask for a way so that when you create a new record of `fleet.vehicle.log.services` those two new fields will then have a default value on them ? Or that you already have tons of `fleet.vehicle.log.services` records and want those to have these default values ?

Comment: Hi, to create a new record of the model, and those two new fields will have a default value on them :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the new api you can override the field from the inherited model and assign a default value either using a static value or a function. Here is an example

```
class Partner(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'
```

ASSIGNING A STATIC DEFAULT VALUE

```
    email = fields.Char(default='static@value.com')
```

ASSIGNING A PROGRAMMATIC DEFAULT VALUE

```
    def _email_default(self):
        return 'programmatic@value.com'

    email = fields.Char(default=_email_default)
```

Using the old api you can do something similar, using a different syntax.

```
class Partner(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'

    _columns = {
        'email': fields.char('Email')  
    }
```

PROGRAMMATIC MEANS OF ASSIGNING DEFAULT VALUE

```
    def _email_default(self, cr, uid, ctx={}):
        return 'programmatic@value.com'

    _defaults = {
        'email': _email_default,
    }
```

STATIC METHOD OF ASSIGNING A DEFAULT VALUE

```
    _defaults = {
        'email': 'static@value.com',
    }
```

Comment: Hi, Thank You very much, awesome explanation, I still don't have results, but I'll open a new question for that!

Comment: A really awesome answer!